# CPI calls to metaplex programs (metadata, token-vault, auction, etc.)

Tags: solana, metaplex

I have a use case where i'd like to update NFT's metadata from a program. How should i construct such instruction?

On a side note, could i use a PDA (owned by custom program) as update authority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to edit the token metadata via [CPI](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs). It's also possible to use a PDA as the update authority, you just need to use the correct seeds when invoking the update instructions.

The `update_metadata_accounts_v2` Rust binding can be found [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/src/instruction.rs#L634=)

Here is an example of a PDA updating metadata https://github.com/Bonfida/name-tokenizer/blob/master/program/src/processor/create_nft.rs#L317=